# Click event in ng2-dragula bag not working

Tags: angular, click, angular2-template, ng2-dragula

I'm using Angular 2 and `ng2-dragula`.

I want to make the drag 'n' drop items in a dragula bag clickable.

This is my **app.component.html**:

```
<div id="rootFrame">
    <div class="tasksFrame">
        <div id="tasksCont" class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
            <div (click)="onClick('ha')">Task 1</div>
            <div (click)="onClick('ba')">Task 2</div>
            <div (click)="onClick('ca')">Task 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="editorFrame">
        <div id="editorCont" class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="showProps" class="propertiesFrame">
        <form>
            Eigenschaft 1<br>
            <input type="text" name="property1"><br> Eigenschaft 2<br>
            <input type="text" name="property2"><br> Eigenschaft 3<br>
            <input type="text" name="property3"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `onClick()` function is never called.

My component **app.component.ts** looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
    viewProviders: [DragulaService],

})
export class AppComponent {


    private showProps = false;

    constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {

        dragulaService.setOptions('first-bag', {
            removeOnSpill: true,
            copy: (el: Element, target: Element, source: Element, sibling: Element): boolean => {
                var editorcont = document.getElementById('editorCont');
                return !target.contains(editorcont);
            },
            accepts: (el: Element, target: Element, source: Element, sibling: Element): boolean => {
                var taskscont = document.getElementById('tasksCont');
                return !target.contains(taskscont); // elements can not be dropped to Tasks Container
            },

        });

    };

    onClick(item: String) {
        //NOT FIRED

        var editorcont = document.getElementById('editorCont');
        // if(editorcont.contains(element)){
        //     this.showProps = true;
        // }
        // else{
        //     this.showProps = false;
        // }
    };
}
```

I think it's because divs are in a dragula container. But how can I make the divs in the dragula container clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick()` is not called because you technically don't click on `div` you drag and drop, you simply left click div and drag it away and that doesn't trigger click event. You need to click on `div`, hold it for the moment and then release it there. It's hard to explain really, maybe [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) definition will clear things up:

> The **onclick** attribute fires on a mouse click on the element.
>
> The **onmousedown** attribute fires when a mouse button is pressed down on the element.
>
> The order of events related to the onmousedown event (for the left/middle mouse button):
>
> - onmousedown
> - onmouseup
> - onclick

Anyway, you are looking for **`mousedown`** event, it is triggered the moment left click is pressed:

```
<div class="tasksFrame">
    <div id="tasksCont" class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div (mousedown)="onClick('ha')">Task 1</div>
        <div (mousedown)="onClick('ba')">Task 2</div>
        <div (mousedown)="onClick('ca')">Task 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```